# Замена текста в строке

Tags: массивы, php, замена

Всем привет!

Такой вопрос.

Есть строка, скажем item.php?dswdfwef={param1}&4545h45h={param2}...

Есть массив

```
array(
  'param1' => 'пока',
  'param2' => 'привет',
  'param3' => 
)
```

Мне нужно в строке заменить {param1} и {param2} на соответствующие значения из массива по ключам.
Понятно, что можно через str_replace(у меня определенный набор параметров).

Как-то можно без str_replace, чтобы автоматом и красиво))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Такой вариант](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/mfd-d2b) сойдет? Правда, на счет того "*чтобы автоматом и красиво*" - не уверен ;)

```
$str = 'item.php?dswdfwef={param1}&4545h45h={param2}';
$new_vals = array(
  'param1' => 'пока',
  'param2' => 'привет',
  'param3' => ''
);
parse_str($str, $output);
$result = array();
foreach($output as $k => $v){
    $v = trim($v,'{}');
    if(isset($new_vals[$v]) && !empty($new_vals[$v])){
        $result[$k] = $new_vals[$v];
    } else {
        // если нужно сохранить пару без замещений
        // в противном случае - убрать else
        $result[$k] = $v;
    }
}
echo urldecode(http_build_query($result));
// item_php?dswdfwef=пока&4545h45h=привет
```

Comment: Хм. Тут получается так, что item_php, а не item.php. То же самое, если домен указан в строке. Это parse_str вытворяет.

Comment: @drop_off, да. Дело рук *urldecode()*. Тогда разбирать надо на части с помощью [parse_url()][1]. Т.е. часть с запросом получаем так:

    $uri = 'item.php?dswdfwef={param1}&4545h45h={param2}';
    $path = parse_url($uri,PHP_URL_PATH); // item.php
    $query = parse_url($uri,PHP_URL_QUERY); // после "?"

$query  - обабатываем и дальше собираем всё вместе. Кстати, если URI может содержать еще и "host", то это так же надо будет учесть

   [1]:http://ua2.php.net/manual/ru/function.parse-url.php

Comment: Мне $output возвращает такую строку уже, до urldecode.


Суть понял. Сейчас попробую с parse_url()

Comment: @drop_off, просто интереса ради - а зачем это вам? Я не люблю регулярки, но в данном случае, всё же предпочел str_replace или что-либо подобное, т.к. гораздо меньше лишних "телодвижений".

Comment: В общем, человек добавляет настройки доступа и ссылки к определенным сайтам. В ссылке заменяет значения параметров на метки {...}.

В виду того, что некоторые параметры динамические(берутся не из настроек), то сразу подставить все нельзя. По этому решил, что замена значений у параметров в ссылке будет сразу со стороны юзера, а в PHP я уже автоматом буду все как нужно заменять и обрабатывать.

Просто я точно не знаю сколько будет параметров, по этому и хотел автоматом, а не через str_replace, чтобы потом не ковырять код...

Answer (score 1):

Есть стандартная функция для постройки запроса - [http_build_query](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.http-build-query.php)

Comment: Не понял как использовать?
Я строку получаю из БД (сохраняется в таком виде)